# Powershell: Catch exception thrown when unable to start a service

Tags: exception, service, powershell, try-catch

I seem unable to catch an exception thrown by `Start-Service`. Here is my code:

```
try
{
    start-service "SomeUnStartableService"
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException]
{
    write-host "got here"
}
```

When I run this, the exception is thrown but not caught:

```
*Service 'SomeUnStartableService' start failed.
At line:3 char:18
+     start-service <<<<  "SomeUnStartableService"
    + CategoryInfo          : OpenError: (System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController:ServiceController) [Start-Service], ServiceCommandException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : StartServiceFailed,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.StartServiceCommand*
```

`$ErrorActionPreference` is set to Stop, so this shouldn't be the problem.

When I alter my code to `catch [Exception]`, the exception is caught and "got here" is printed.

Does `start-service` throw a `ServiceCommandException` or something else? It looks as though it is but I cannot catch it!

--- Edit ---

Ideally I could write the following, and throw an exception if `start-service` did not throw an exception, and only catch an exception thrown by `start-service`:

```
try
{
    start-service "SomeUnStartableService"
    throw (new-object Exception("service started when expected not to start"))
}
catch [Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException]
{
    write-host "got here"
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I usually don't limit the catch-phrase but handle the exceptions with logical tests within the catch-block:

```
try
{
  start-service "SomeUnStartableService" -ea Stop
}
catch
{
   if ( $error[0].Exception -match "Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException")
   {
      #do this
   }
   else
   {
      #do that
   }
}
```

Maybe not as clean, and may result in huge catch blocks. But if it works... ;)

Comment: It's a shame it's not as neat as catching the specific exception, but I suppose if that can't be done this is the next best thing.

Answer (score 24):

Try/Catch works only on terminating errors. Use the ErrorAction parameter with a value of Stop to make the error a terminating error and then you'll be able to catch it:

```
try
{
    start-service "SomeUnStartableService" -ErrorAction Stop
}
catch
{
    write-host "got here"
}
```

UPDATE:

When you set $ErrorActionPreference to 'stop' (or use -ErrorAction Stop) the error type you get is ActionPreferenceStopException, so you can use it to catch the error.

```
$ErrorActionPreference='stop'

try
{
    start-service SomeUnStartableService
}
catch [System.Management.Automation.ActionPreferenceStopException]
{
    write-host "got here"
}
```

}

Comment: if $ErrorActionPreference is set to Stop it's not enough ?

Comment: As $ErrorActionPreference is set to 'Stop' it makes no difference adding -erroraction Stop. The above code catches a general [Exception], however I wish to catch only the exception thrown by start-service, meaning that I could for example throw another exception in the try block but not have it caught in the catch.

Comment: Sorry, missed that part. I've update the thread, check it out.

Comment: That ActionPreferenceStopException is *really* unintuitive. Thanks for explaining! I thought PowserShell was just ignoring the $ErrorActionPreference value when I tried to catch the exception that I really want to catch.

Answer (score 2):

To discover your exception you can use :

```
try
{
  start-service "SomeUnStartableService" -ea Stop
}
catch
{
 $_.exception.gettype().fullname
}
```

---

Edited : Here is a kind of bypass with `SystemException`

```
try
{
  start-service "SomeUnStartableService" -ea Stop
}
catch [SystemException]
{
 write-host "got here"
}
```

Comment: This returns Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException, which is what I was trying to catch above.

Comment: The edit does help and I suppose fits the purpose so I've voted it up, but I don't think it can be the answer as it's a bit of a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

"Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ServiceCommandException" will also be true when not run elevated. Just saying.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31312691)