# Try/catch is not working with Start-Service

Tags: powershell

My problem is really simple (I think). To catch when a service cannot be started and throw a message. Really the only reason it should fail is if the service is disabled but I want to let the user know that. I [saw this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676483/powershell-catch-exception-thrown-when-unable-to-start-a-service) but none of the answers seemed to help since they're talking about filtering the catch with if statements and I can't even seem to get a basic catch working like so:

```
Write-Host "Starting Services ..."

    $svc = Get-Service -DisplayName "*lar*" | where { $_.Status -Like "Stop*" }
    if ( $svc )
    {
        foreach ( $item in $svc )
        {
            Write-Host "Starting"$item.Name 
            try { Start-Service $item.Name 
            } 
            catch {
                Write-Host "Could not start service:" $item.Name
            }
        }
    }
```

I do get an error when running, but not my write-host message in the catch
[image: message received]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Start-Service` on a disabled service throws a non-terminating error. For `catch` to work, you need a terminating error. You can force the error to be terminating by using `-ErrorAction Stop`.

```
try {
    Start-Service $item.Name -ErrorAction Stop
} 
catch {
    Write-Host "Could not start service:" $item.Name
}
```